# PHP Pars Array from PHP

Tags: php, arrays, parsing

I know there are similar questions and I have used some of them to get this far but having a problem. I have a php file with an array of arrays like as follows:

```
    <?php

      error_reporting(0);
        $items = array(
          array( "name" => "Shirts",
          "size" => "100",
          "country" => "United States",
          "color" => "red",
          "sleeve"=>"short",
         "neck" =>"crew",
         ),
```

Of course there are many more entries but similar in structural to the above. I am including the file and trying to parse the value for color and sleeve.

```
    foreach ($val['items']['Shirts'] as $result) {

       $color = $result['color']; 
       $sleeve = $result['sleeve'];
    }
```

When the script is executed, it displays the complete list of arrays. Not sure what to do to just get the ones needed.
Thanks

Comment: `$val['items']['Shirts']` -> `$items` ?!

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Your array which you show us from the included if has the variable name: `$items` so use it like this e.g. `foreach ($items as $result)`

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly Your array structure?

Try to rebuild Your array to following structure.

```
$items = array(

    'Shirts'        =>      array(

        array(

            'size'      =>      100,
            'country'   =>      'United States',
            'color'     =>      'red',
            'sleeve'    =>      'short',
            'neck'      =>      'crew'
        ),
        array(

            'size'      =>      120,
            'country'   =>      'United States',
            'color'     =>      'green',
            'sleeve'    =>      'short',
            'neck'      =>      'crew'
        ),
        array(

            'size'      =>      140,
            'country'   =>      'United States',
            'color'     =>      'blue',
            'sleeve'    =>      'short',
            'neck'      =>      'crew'
        )
    )
);

if(count($items['Shirts'])){

    foreach($items['Shirts'] AS $index => $shirt_data){

        $color = $shirt_data['color'];
        $sleeve = $shirt_data['sleeve'];
    }
}
```